# How to use two pages of a View with the same path depending on users's profile?

Tags: views, 8

I created a View on a custom Content Entity.
I'd like to have 2 pages:

- the first with all the fields from my entity, no filters, accessible
  by users with Edit rights on the entity,
- the second one with some of
  the fields, filtered by one criteria, accessible by users with View
  rights on the entity.

And, of course, with the same path, e.g. [mysite]/myEntity.
How do I do that?
I use Drupal 8.3.4.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 this was quite easy to implement just using Views. In D8 I couldn't manage to implement it only with Views.

You can create a panel page with two different variants. Place the relevant block in each variant and control the accessibility though the 'Page access'. (I used roles but you can even create your custom condition)